# OpenCL synchronization in integration-like systems

Tags: c, synchronization, opencl, simulation

I have an matrix of vectors (x, y and z coordinates) and I need to update then each time step on the simulation. A simple simulation has ~10⁶ time steps on average.

So far I thought:

1. Run all the integration on kernel, so I would have something like

```
kernel void Simulate(global Vector* matrix, const int nSteps)
{
    int i = get_global_id(0);
    int j = get_global_id(1);
    for(int t = 0; t < nSteps; t++)
    {
        DoSomething(i, j, matrix, t); <- depends on other elements of the matrix
        barrier(CLK_GLOBAL_MEM_FENCE);
    }
}
```

on the device code and on host code a simple `clEnqueueNDRangeKernel(queue, kernel, 2, NULL, globalWork, localWork, 0, NULL, NULL)` call.

2. Using the kernel to do a single time step, so something like

```
kernel void Step(global Vector* matrix, const int t)
{
    int i = get_global_id(0);
    int j = get_global_id(1);
    DoSomething(i, j, matrix, t); <- depends on other elements of the matrix
}
```

and on host

```
for(int t = 0; t < nSteps; t++)
{
    clEnqueueNDRangeKernel(queue, kernel, 2, NULL, globalWork, NULL, 0, NULL, NULL);
    clFinish(queue);
}
```

in this case I think on don't passing `localWork` to `clEnqueueNDRangeKernel`, since I was only using it for synchronization.

But I ran into troubles. For the first attempt:

1. My graphics card only supports 1024 local work, this means `localWork = {32, 32}` at max, and for synchronization purposes, all the `globalWork` must be in `localWork` (only 1 work group), since `barrier` only works within a work group. But my matrices can have any dimensions (typically 288x288).
2. Some previous experience showed me that huge loop on GPU crashes everything. This must be a problem on my GPU, as its pretty old.

By this I mean the first attempt its impossible.

For the second attempt I didn't implement that, but I can think in only one problem: Calling `clEnqueueNDRangeKernel` and `clFinish` could, and probably, lead to performance issues, since it takes some time to call both functions. In simulations code everything must be at maximum performance, no overhead allowed.

Is there another way to do this? I already took a look on [1], specifically on the Case Studies section, but it was not very clear for me.

[1] Munshi, OpenCL Programming Guide.

Answer (score 1):

In short: Approach 2 is the way to do it.

Approach 1 does not work for more than a single workgroup because global synchronization within a kernel is not possible. Running only a single workgroup utilizes only small part of the hardware, so performance is very poor.

Approach 2 provides global synchronization after the kernel for a single time step has finished. Most algorithms require global synchronization between time steps, so this is the (only) way to do it. If global range is sufficiently large (a few Million), the hardware is fully saturated and performance is at peak efficiency. When the kernel is finished, the next kernel is immediately queued, so there is no significant idle time. This is how all GPU simulation codes operate and this way you can reach 100% efficiency in roofline model if your kernel is well optimized.

A few more tips:

- Parallelize across a 1D linear index and compute the x- and y-position for any particular matrix element in the kernel by integer division and modulo. This gives you more freedom on matrix size dimensions.
- Set the 1D workgroup size to 32 or a multiple of 32. Threads within a workgroup operate in warps on a hardware level, and a warp is 32 threads.
- The loop itself is certainly not the cause of the crashes you experience. Probably you allocate too much device memory.
- Look into local/shared memory optimization, also known as cache tiling. This trick can boost speed by several times by using shared memory (L1 cache of the device) in matrix-type operations.

Comment: Thanks, so approach 2 its the only way to global synchronization.
I remembered that `clEnqueueReadBuffer` and `clEnqueueWriteBuffer` takes the longer time to run. So lets say I need to calculate something extra, that returns a scalar, from the matrix, the best way its to calculate it on the kernel and reading that result on the host, right?

About the 1D linear index, you mean to set `globalWork[1]={nRows*nCols}` and work this way?

About the crashes, I would agree with you, but for some reason when I increase `nSteps` (using the same matrix) eveything crashes.

Comment: 1) `clEnqueueReadBuffer`/`clEnqueueWriteBuffer` are very slow (PCIe bandwidth is only a few GB/s), so don't use them in the main loop if possible. Only after the simulation is finished, use them to copy results to the CPU. If you need to do intermediary steps on the CPU, try to parallelize them on the GPU as well to entirely avoid PCIe transfer. 2) `globalWork[0]={nRows*nCols}`, remember to count from `0` 3) Strange... is the matrix filled with NaNs at some point?

Comment: 1)I trying to work around the problem about `clEnqueueReadBuffer / clEnqueueWriteBuffer`. Basically on one part of the program I need to get a scalar from the matrix, and read the entire matrix on host and getting this scalar on host its very slow, so I'm trying to get this scalar on the device and then reading it on host (as I think reading a single element will probably be faster). 2) My bad, I wrote it wrong, I was meaning on definition `size_t globalWork[1]={nRows*nCols};`. 3) No, just random numbers between -1 and 1. I saw something about GPU watchdog, but I'm no sure if it's the case.